# how to read txt file by skipping character? In C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm trying to read a txt file, get some information and put it in variables, but I'm not succeeding, because each line of my txt file starts with a character, and I need to skip that character.

Input file:

```
T1, 3, 0
T2, 3, 1
T3, 2, 2
```

I need to ignore the **T** and just take the numbers. I've tried using `%*c` in `fscanf`, but it didn't work.

```
int initialize()
{
    int n, n1, n2, n3, i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error locating the file. Please try again!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) != EOF)
    {

        p[i] = n1;

        if (p[i] > MAX)
        {
            printf("Woah! I am not a super computer. Please input upto 100 processes :)\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        b[i] = n2;

        a[i] = n3;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

I apologize about my English, I'm from Brazil.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "T%d,%d,%d", &n1, &n2, &n3) == 3)`

Comment: Even better, `fgets()` first, then `sscanf()` (or write your own parser)... for a **much** better way of dealing with validation and/or errors.

Comment: The `%*c` in `fscanf` didn't work to skip the T because `%c` does not filter whitespace and was reading the previous newline. It would have needed a space, as `" %*c"` to ignore the newline.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things.

You want to read a `T`, so simply add a `T` to the format string:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "T%d, %d, %d", &n1, &n2, &n3) != EOF)
```

But this is not a good error check. You should change `!= EOF` to `== 3`. Read the [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) about the return value.

A better approach is to use `fgets` for input and `sscanf` to parse the input. See this question for more reading: [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/6699433)